# How can I edit Google Spreadsheets Cells using the API?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have a form and <s>an API</s> a Google Apps Script attached to it.

After sending the form I want to confirm that the script ran successfully with no errors by adding a value `V` to the last column of the form response's spreadsheet.

But I can't find any way to edit an existing row. Can someone help me with that?

---

Additional information from comments:

```
var responsesSSID = SpreadsheetApp.openById('*****************'); 
var values = responsesSSID.getDataRange().getValues(); 
values[values.length-1][values[].length-1] = "V";
```

I couldn't find anything here (for the next line) that will work.

Comment: Can you please provide the code that you tried?

Comment: <blink>var responsesSSID   = SpreadsheetApp.openById('*****************');
var values = responsesSSID.getDataRange().getValues();
values[values.length-1][values[].length-1] = "V";</blink>
I couldn't find anything here (for the next line) that will work.

Comment: I don't think you are actually using the Spreadsheet API - instead, you're using Google Apps Script. I've edited your question accordingly; if you disagree, you can roll back the change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want to update/edit the last column of the last row of your spreadsheet :

```
var sprdkey = '0Ai4sb45QfOAQdGhRWEtQaTR0enVHUHlxSTlobkVtenc';

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sprdkey).getActiveSheet();

var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

var lastCol = sheet.getLastColumn();

sheet.getRange(lastRow , lastCol).setValue("V");
```

If you need to edit any other cell in the spreadsheet, you just need to pass the appropriate parameters to the **getRange(row_no, col_no)** function.

Hope this helps!